# c# json Deserialize not fill all the data in the class

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm have this problem that when I run this application only some fields are filled and the remaining stay null??
Here is Deserialize method code:

```
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var movies = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              
                   

                  var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                  var moviesList = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(movies);
                 
                    }
                else throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string status_message { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data 
    {
        public Movie movie { get; set; }
    }

    public class Movie 
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string imdb_code { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string title_english { get; set; }
        public string title_long { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public float rating { get; set; }
        public int runtime { get; set; }
        public List<string> genres { get; set; }
        public int download_count { get; set; }
        public int like_count { get; set; }
        public string description_intro { get; set; }
        public string description_full { get; set; }
        public string yt_trailer_code { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string mpa_rating { get; set; }
        public string background_image { get; set; }
        public string background_image_original { get; set; }
        public string small_cover_image { get; set; }
        public string medium_cover_image { get; set; }
        public string large_cover_image { get; set; }
        public List<Torrent> torrents { get; set; }
        public string date_uploaded { get; set; }
        public int date_uploaded_unix { get; set; }
    }
 public class Torrent
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
        public string quality { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int seeds { get; set; }
        public int peers { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public int size_bytes { get; set; }
        public string date_uploaded { get; set; }
        public int date_uploaded_unix { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int server_time { get; set; }
        public string server_timezone { get; set; }
        public int api_version { get; set; }
        public string execution_time { get; set; }
    }
```

the only field that is set is status and status_message
the other 2 at RootObject stay null

Edit:
Here is how json looks ():

```
{  "status": "ok",
  "status_message": "Query was successful",
  "data": {
    "movie": {
      "id": 100,
      "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/movies\/a-lot-like-love-2005",
      "imdb_code": "tt0391304",
      "title": "A Lot Like Love",
      "title_english": "A Lot Like Love",
      "title_long": "A Lot Like Love (2005)",
      "slug": "a-lot-like-love-2005",
      "year": 2005,
      "rating": 6.6,
      "runtime": 107,
      "genres": [ "Action", "Comedy", "Drama", "Romance" ],
      "download_count": 86626,
      "like_count": 191,
      "description_intro": "On a flight from Los Angeles to New York, Oliver and Emily make a connection, only to decide that they are poorly suited to be together. Over the next seven years, however, they are reunited time and time again, they go from being acquaintances to close friends to ... lovers? \u2014IMDb Editors",
      "description_full": "On a flight from Los Angeles to New York, Oliver and Emily make a connection, only to decide that they are poorly suited to be together. Over the next seven years, however, they are reunited time and time again, they go from being acquaintances to close friends to ... lovers? \u2014IMDb Editors",
      "yt_trailer_code": "MRPr34vEbC8",
      "language": "en",
      "mpa_rating": "PG-13",
      "background_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/A_Lot_Like_Love_2005\/background.jpg",
      "background_image_original": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/A_Lot_Like_Love_2005\/background.jpg",
      "small_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/A_Lot_Like_Love_2005\/small-cover.jpg",
      "medium_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/A_Lot_Like_Love_2005\/medium-cover.jpg",
      "large_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/A_Lot_Like_Love_2005\/large-cover.jpg",
      "torrents": [
        {
          "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/torrent\/download\/F6F33A8D26D180F7C5BA0B042D22139A782F4FDF",
          "hash": "F6F33A8D26D180F7C5BA0B042D22139A782F4FDF",
          "quality": "720p",
          "type": "bluray",
          "seeds": 1,
          "peers": 4,
          "size": "700.27 MB",
          "size_bytes": 734286316,
          "date_uploaded": "2015-10-31 21:00:11",
          "date_uploaded_unix": 1446321611
        },
        {
          "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/torrent\/download\/40A2F78FA8BE1834335C7927FAD775642E53FF44",
          "hash": "40A2F78FA8BE1834335C7927FAD775642E53FF44",
          "quality": "1080p",
          "type": "bluray",
          "seeds": 9,
          "peers": 9,
          "size": "1.40 GB",
          "size_bytes": 1503238554,
          "date_uploaded": "2015-10-31 21:00:15",
          "date_uploaded_unix": 1446321615
        }
      ],
      "date_uploaded": "2015-10-31 21:00:11",
      "date_uploaded_unix": 1446321611
    }
  },
  "@meta": {
    "server_time": 1627510627,
    "server_timezone": "CET",
    "api_version": 2,
    "execution_time": "0 ms"
  }
}
```

this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long this text is very very very long

text above just for bypass stack overflow :)

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: how das the json look?

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is prehistoric. consider Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json - this would also allow you to decorate properties with `[JsonProperty]` or `[JsonPropertyName]` attributes to specify the property name in the json so you don't have to violate c# naming conventions -> `[JsonProperty("yt_trailer_code")]public string YoutubeTrailerCode {get;set;}`

Comment: Make life easy; paste your JSON into http://quicktype.io and it will make all the classes and the deser code, and give comments showing how to use it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without that, it's going to be really hard to help you. (I'd also recommend using idiomatic .NET property names, then using attributes to configure how those properties are represented in JSON.)

Comment: share your json

Comment: I edited it and share the json :)

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried it with no luck data field and meta field still Null

Comment: "text above just for bypass stack overflow :)" - rather than trying to bypass the quality filters, please just *improve the quality of the question instead*. It's very unlikely you really need *all* of that, either in terms of code or JSON, to demonstrate the problem. If you'd just included two JSON fields, one of which worked and one of which didn't, and the corresponding code, along with a genuine [mcve] for the deserialization instead of "the second half of a method that already has a response", and a description of the problem, you wouldn't have run into the quality filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @CaiusJard I tried it with no luck data field and meta field still Null

You must have done something different to me then:

[image]

#### A:

I took your json and saved it into a file called `some.json` and set it to copy to the output directory (so i can load it easily). I wrote a line of code that loads it

#### B:

I went to quicktype.io as advised in the comments and pasted your json in there, it gave me some nice C# classes and a comment on how to use it; I literally just pasted this onto the end of my Program.cs

#### C:

I added the `using` and the line of code in the comment to my program.

---

I didn't have Newtonsoft installed. The comment says to install newtonsoft. The simplest way to do this is scroll to the bottom and point to any of the errors under the class names from newtonsoft; it's so popular that Visual studio knows thenames of its classes and will offer to install for you as a "click the lightbulb for help fixing this error":

[image]

#### D:

After installing I put a breakpoint on the code and ran it. I stepped over the line that loads the json and now you can see in the Locals window at the bottom `someThing` truly is populated with data, including the Data and Meta

---

All done, with just 3 lines of code, and only one of them I had to write - bonus! :D

Comment: I have no affiliation with QuickType.io

Comment: No problem. On SO the way we say thanks is to click the up arrow and the grey check mark next to the question, by the way..